# trying to run kextutil on kext file returns permissions error

Tags: xcode, macos, iokit, kernel-extension

Hi Stackoverflow Community.

Trying to run through the following tutorial - so I can learn how to code a driver util.
http://www.robertopasini.com/index.php/2-uncategorised/625-osx-creating-a-device-driver

I'm at the point where I'm trying to run kextutil on the kext file that my build produces.
Per the instructions I copy it to my temp folder.
But I'm getting the following error:

```
admins-Mac-mini:Debug admin$ kextutil -n -t /tmp/ssvac.kext
Skipping staging and system policy checks because not running as root, expect staging errors.
Kext rejected due to improper filesystem permissions: <OSKext 0x7f91d402f140 [0x7fff898b2cc0]> { URL = "file:///private/tmp/ssvac.kext/", ID = "myappleid.ssvac" }
Code Signing Failure: code signature is invalid
Authentication Failures: 
    File owner/permissions are incorrect (must be root:wheel, nonwritable by group/other): 
        /private/tmp/ssvac.kext
        Contents
        _CodeSignature
        CodeResources
        MacOS
        ssvac
        Info.plist

Diagnostics for /private/tmp/ssvac.kext:
Authentication Failures: 
    File owner/permissions are incorrect (must be root:wheel, nonwritable by group/other): 
        /private/tmp/ssvac.kext
        Contents
        _CodeSignature
        CodeResources
        MacOS
        ssvac
        Info.plist

admins-Mac-mini:Debug admin$
```

I tried to change the permissions / owner like so:

```
admins-Mac-mini:Debug admin$ chown root:wheel /tmp/ssvac.kext/

admins-Mac-mini:Debug admin$ ls -lah /tmp/ssvac.kext/
total 0
drwxrwxrwx  3 root   wheel    96B 16 Oct 16:37 .
drwxrwxrwt  7 root   wheel   224B 19 Oct 08:08 ..
drwxr-xr-x  5 admin  wheel   160B 16 Oct 16:37 Contents
admins-Mac-mini:Debug admin$ kextutil -n -t /tmp/ssvac.kext
```

Not sure exactly how to resolve it.
If you have any tips, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks!

EDIT 1

```
My mistake was when I copied from the debug folder to /tmp/, I didn't use the -r switch.  Now that I have, this is the error I'm getting: 

admins-Mac-mini:Debug admin$ cp -r ssvac.kext/ /tmp/
admins-Mac-mini:Debug admin$ sudo kextutil /tmp/
Contents/                     com.apple.launchd.GufwRL5Sf0/ com.google.Keystone/          powerlog/                     ssvac.kext/
admins-Mac-mini:Debug admin$ sudo kextutil /tmp/ssvac.kext/
Password:
Untrusted kexts are not allowed
Kext with invalid signature (-67050) denied: /private/var/db/KernelExtensionManagement/Staging/tmp.RLlmC1/59AFE9EA-12E3-42C0-B3FC-E98EF987D9B2.kext
Bundle (/private/tmp/ssvac.kext) failed to validate, deleting: /private/var/db/KernelExtensionManagement/Staging/tmp.RLlmC1/59AFE9EA-12E3-42C0-B3FC-E98EF987D9B2.kext
Unable to stage kext (/private/tmp/ssvac.kext) to secure location.
admins-Mac-mini:Debug admin$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the `ls` output, kexts are really directories containing at minimum an Info.plist file, and code signing information in a predefined directory layout. (starting with a `Contents` subdirectory) Usually it also contains a binary executable. *All* files and subdirectories in the kext must have appropriate permissions for the kext to be considered for loading. This means permissions must be applied *recursively* with the `-R` flag when using `chown`.

Instead of using `chown`, I generally recommend simply copying the kext to a temporary location (for testing, prior to macOS 11) or `/Library/Extensions` (from macOS 11 onwards, or when deploying, or when testing the kext's boot time behaviour) *as* the root user as you then don't run into problems trying to replace it with an updated version as an unprivileged user during your code/compile/load/debug cycle:

```
# Copies kext to /tmp, owned by root
sudo cp -r "path/to/built.kext" "/tmp/"
# Attempts to load kext
sudo kextutil "/tmp/built.kext"
```

*(Obligatory disclaimer pointing out that many types of kext are now deprecated, and you'll want to make sure that writing a kext really, really, **really** is the correct way forward for your project.)*

Comment: I think my mistake was not copying the entire folder to /tmp.  I copied just the one file.  But now that I did the recursive, I'm getting a different error.  Please see Edit 1

Comment: @dot After your edit, your question is now essentially 2 questions, [which is bad for various reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741/611605). I'll give you the quick answer for the second question, but if that's not enough, please ask it as a new question. `Kext with invalid signature (-67050) denied` means exactly what it says: you need to sign your kext with a valid kext signing certificate and get the kext notarised, *or* you need to turn off kext signing validation by turning off that part of SIP (System Integrity Protection) or all of SIP.

Comment: yup makes sense!